# PHP MyDirectory cron job warning in Administrator area

Tags: php, cron

I have a site built in phpmydirectory.

When I go to the Admin panel, I get the warning below.
Can anybody tell me how to fix it?  Temp folder has permissions 755, and I have tried with 777 as well.

```
Scheduled tasks have not run in the last 5 days. Please ensure the /files/temp/ folder is writable. If it continues to fail, please setup your cron job to run hourly using one of the following:

Using PHP:
```

php -q /home/content/60/8955660/html/cron.php 2f1d8c64644e7d9d462d8602aed5e6a3

```
Using GET:
```

GET http://www.peydaa.com/cron.php?c=2f1d8c64644e7d9d462d8602aed5e6a3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that Apache web server group called "**www-data**" is the owner of "/files/temp/"

Example:

chmod -R 775 www-data /files/temp/

chown -R www-data:www-data /files/temp/